# Is there any significance to the Valyrian Stone vault door of Qarth?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

This may seem inconsequential to the immediate plot and story of *Game of Thrones*, but I was wondering if there is ANY significance to the vault in [Qarth](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Qarth) having a Valyrian Stone door?

[image: Qarth Vault Door]

Is there any history explaining how the door came to be be?

Comment: Significance beyond it being the strongest stone so next to impossible to break into?

Comment: You seem to seek an answer from history. All of the lore and history is based in the books. In the books, Xaro Xhoan Daxos never had such a vault, nor did he make any claims about it. Nor is there such a thing as "Valyrian Stone" door. Valyrians did work stone like no other man could, by fusing them together as if they melted the whole thing and forged it like a sword out of steel. Also Qartheen never had any direct interaction with Valyria AFAIK. Climate declined their civilisation when Valyria ruled and after her fall, the Dothraki fell on Qartheen states, leaving only Qarth.

Comment: That being said, Qarth is after all a trading city and hub of Jade Sea trade. It is not impossible for them to get hold of valyrian relics. Xaro showed a number of them to Daenerys like Valyrian scrolls, maps etc.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. Yes, I was looking for history beyond the Xaro plot of the second season's TV narrative. If there was any evidence if this is also like the other Valyarion materials mentioned and/if there was any evidence of old Valyaria relating to the history of Qarth.

Comment: @Aegon that is precisely what I was curious about.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The immediate significance of the door is simply that it is next to impossible to break into and the material itself is extremely strong as Xaro himself explains in the scene where the door is revealed.

> **Xaro:** The door and the vault is made of Valyrian stone. The hardest steel does not make a mark. I offered the greatest locksmiths in Qarth their weight in gold if they could break into it. I made the same offer to the greatest thieves. They all went home empty-handed. The only thing that can open this door is this key.
>
> <sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 2 Episode 5, "The Ghost of Harrenhal"</sub>

If you're looking for any further significance or history of the material or door than that then I'm afraid you're out of luck. The only information we get on it in the show is that small paragraph by Xaro.

That said in the books there is the material called dragonstone which is probably what Valyrian Stone in the show is meant to be.

> The heart of Old Volantis is the city-withinthe-city—an immense labyrinth of ancient palaces, courtyards, towers, temples, cloisters, bridges, and cellars, all contained within the great oval of the Black Walls raised by the Freehold of Valyria in the first flush of its youthful expansion. Two hundred feet tall, and so thick that six four-horse chariots can race along their battlements side by side (as they do each year to celebrate the founding of the city), **these seamless walls of fused black dragonstone, harder than steel or diamond, stand in mute testimony to Volantis's origins as a military outpost.**
>
> <sub>*The World of Ice and Fire*, The Free Cities: Volantis</sub>

This material is used within many of the Valyrian's buildings and is extremely strong and made of fused stone. It is said it is created through the use of magic.

Comment: Thank you! I will accept your answer! Yes, I was looking beyond that Xaro plot, if there was any historic connection between Qarth and Old Valyeria in the books or secondary sources anywhere. Even a good theory would of sufficed. On the TV series I had noticed that the Ancient Egyptian-like designs at the front gate are similar designs to parts of the Red Keep...